# Should I say "data sets of race times of various cars" or something better?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I say "data sets of race times of various cars" or something better? I am concerned that the "of" don't sound quite right.

Comment: Use as many nouns in a row as you can. *Car race time record data set collations.*

Comment: I would use *for various cars*, just to avoid the repetition of *of*, although both prepositions are grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases you could just say "sets of car race times".

In the original phrase, the word "data" is redundant, since care race times are obviously data. Substituting "car" for "cars" lets you eliminate the "various".

If you want to keep the original structure, you could say "sets of race times *for* various cars".

Comment: *data* is not redundant in *data set* here; *data set* is a technical term the meaning of which isn't conveyed by either *data* or *set*.

Comment: @Peter: I am aware that a data set is (usually tabular) collection of data. As I said, in *many* contexts the fact that the data is tabular is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Say: *datasets of various cars’ racing times*.

Answer (score 1):

It's an unwieldy, but grammatically correct, way to put it. "[D]ata sets of cars' race times" could also work. The problem isn't your phrasing, but that dealing with multiple sets of data about multiple cars with (at least one) race time per car is itself a little unwieldy.

If you have to talk about it a lot, give it a memorable nickname or acronym.

Comment: Establishing a term of reference is a reasonable idea, but I would avoid giving it a "silly" nickname.

Comment: Come on, silly nicknames make everything better! ...okay I'll fix it. :( is "memorable" better?